# How to type a normal quotation mark without auto-substitution?

Tags: macos, text-input

Many apps offer the option to turn off auto-substitution on quotation marks (") such as TextEdit, but many other apps do not have such settings, for example LibreOffice.

So how to type a normal quotation mark in those cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenOffice and LibreOffice, you go to Format > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options > Localized Options and uncheck the boxes for Replace under Single Quotes and Double Quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key. It works everywhere that uses the System smart quotes. I don't know if LibreOffice does or not.

Comment: control + " doesn't type anything in LibreOffice.

Comment: Then it that case it is overriding part of the System, probably capturing all control key strokes. You can see the above work in TextEdit. Problem is that most software stuffs with the plain System text entry and therefore the answer becomes app specific.

Comment: I type everything in Byword or TextEdit. TextEdit even does Word docs well these days.

Comment: MS Word and its clones traditionally do not use Apple's spellcheck or autocorrection services but have more elaborate alternatives built in.